# What do saints supposedly do on behalf of humans?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word that denotes what saints do (according to religious belief) on behalf of worshipers? The word starts with "inter-", I think.

This would be an example sentence where this word would be used:

> The god of thunder was preparing to execute the man to punish him for stealing a
>   lightening bolt, but a saint _____ to delay punishment because there
>   were also gods involved in the theft.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific what you mean by "what saints do to god". Please see the guidance [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: The reference is to the role of saints as go-betweens seeking God's favor and help on behalf of the faithful who pray to them.

Comment: What do saints do ***for*** God.

Comment: I see the point--interceding isn't something saints do *to* God, as implied by the question. It might be better written as "What is the word that denotes requests made of God by saints (according to religious beliefs)  on behalf of worshipers?"

Comment: Are you referring to saints in Christianity or in another tradition? Are you referring to the Abrahamic God (who is traditionally capitalized) or any generic deity?

Answer (score 18):

The word is "intercede", "to intervene between parties with a view to reconciling differences ". https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intercede Also, see Wikipedia's article on [Intercession of saints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercession_of_saints). Here's an article on "[intercessory prayer](https://www.allaboutprayer.org/intercessory-prayer.htm)". Oh, here's the Catholic Encyclopedia's article on [Intercession (Mediation)](https://www.catholic.org/encyclopedia/view.php?id=6146).

Comment: and/or interlocutors

Comment: I'm having a hard time coming up with examples of saints being described as "interlocutors". Do you have any?

Comment: Yes, they intercede on behalf of humans vis-ã-vis God. Interlocutor doesn't work because it puts the parties at the same level.